# foam sword hit detection on vest

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, relay, design, embedded

**Does anybody know how I would make a soft foam sword detect a hit on a vest?** This is for a dueling game, sort of like fencing, with nerf weapons. I'm hoping to eventually create a system using an arduino.

These are some sensors I've looked into already but I haven't found enough similar projects to know for sure that they would be appropriate:

**Membrane relay switches**
this would require no hardware in the weapon. Can detect the intensity of a hit. but it could be detected by any kind of contact, even a crinkling vest.

**Magnetic contact switches**
Magnets inside of the sword would be detected when in close proximity to the vest. would make the weapon heavier, possible need for wiring between weapon and vest, difficulty getting the magnetism through a foam weapon.

**Voltage Divider**
foam sword needs a conductive material. Possible electrocution. Possible need for wiring between weapon and vest.

**Frequency generator & microphones**
Emit a supersonic frequency that is detected when in proximity of the vest. Difficulty getting the frequency through a foam weapon, possibility of water damage to microphones. Interference between many people using the same process.

Comment: Didn't you ask this today already?

Comment: I apologize, I'm new to this site. That post was poorly written and didn't properly convey my issue, as expressed by many commenters. That post has since been taken down.

Comment: maybe something like an RFID tag in the sword and an RFID receiver in the vest ... that way you could distinguish between swords for multiplayer battles, and you could even commit "suicide" ... lol

Comment: Can you at least have a wire to some metallic coated ping pong ball or equiv.  If the contact is only near field sensed, it will be prone to disputes. Hey you didn't touch me. Thus contact must be physical. And voltage is not more than a battery

Comment: what about an optical system using IR LEDs

Comment: Electrocution is a bad assumption if the sword is high resistance and has a tip bigger than an electrical socket.

Comment: @jsotola thanks! ill try this out, I hope it can act quick enough. Do you know if there's a way this could detect direction aswell? So that I could put the receiver in a helmet then it would only detect when it's near its vertical axis?

Comment: Close only counts in horse-shoes

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Thanks mate, I'll test conductive foams. Since its a toy, it'll be best for the outside material to be as soft as possible.

Comment: Black CMOS conductive foam should be good for < 1M Ohm but then one needs a partially conductive suit. Which is a bigger issue.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, close counts in horse-shoes and grenades ... lol

Comment: As a prior art check, have you looked at fencing?  They're obviously not using foam swords, but they literally have a hundred years of practice making this kind of thing work at the Olympic level.  It'd be a solid datapoint to use when narrowing down the scope of this project.

Comment: @CortAmmon 100 years ago, or 20 years ago for that matter, they didn't have MEMS accelerometers. I bet fencing is orthodox, using old techniques out of tradition. Kind of like football still has live linesmen to determine offside etc, even though that's a technology of the 1800:s.

Comment: @Lundin but it's still prior art.  It's a great place to gather requirements.  For example, when fencing foil, only strikes with the tip count, but when fencing saber, the entire blade is a scoring surface.  What are the requirements for  unshiney's game?  Making the decision between those two styles would dramatically change how you make the 21st century hardware.

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm having a hard time finding just exactly how fencing equipment achieves what it does. From what I've found its something like small current in the blade or tip which connects to armor that is always searching for that current? I was hoping to achieve this current in a foam blade using conductive foam, at this this is something I'm already going to test moving forward.

Comment: @CortAmmon nevermind, looks like I found a rough outline. It's good enough to understand roughly that it's a little more hardware heavy than I might need. All the conductive materials required in fencing are too cumbersome for a toy. I may keep voltage dividers in mind but we'll see how it turns out.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just a basic arduino + accelerometer duo? A 'hit' response will be significantly more distinguished than a 'swing'.

Comment: And there's even accelerometers that have a built-in "shock detection".

Comment: Yep, definitely plenty of good accels to choose from. [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156352/understanding-how-to-use-an-accelerometer-to-detect-vehicle-collisions) poster had a similar application. Guessing that this accelerometer would work well for 'hit' detection

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a better solution.  Possibly a flexible polyresistor film inside a foam stick with stripleds inside. So you only need to detect a drop in resistance from ~1M to detect a touch. ( with sufficient bend)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put a microphone in the sword. You should be able to distinguish a hit from a swing or a near hit.

If you use a lot of padding around the microphone, then you will be able to make it so nearby shouts will be low, but people touching the sword will be audible.

Answer (score -1):

Capacitive screen. The "foam" in the sword may need to be engineered to be capable of holding a charge, like your finger is to a capacitive touch screen user interface. Fingers and hands or any skin would also activate it, but the "costume" could include NON-conductive gloves / clothes so that only the sword is available to activate it. Cost may be prohibitive though...

Comment: It seems like "suicide" in this dueling game will be somewhat of an issue. It seems like creating a sensor that only detects direct contact will be best, so finding a soft conductive foam for the outside of the weapon is a must.